# Magento: Assign Static Block to All Store's Homepages

Tags: magento, e-commerce

```
  <cms_index_index>
 <reference name="content">
  <block type="cms/block" name="home-page-block">
  <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>home-page-block</block_id></action>
</block>
 </reference>
<cms_index_index>
```

The above code adds Static Block to Homepage, I have added a static block as per above code. But its not displayed on all stores. As All stores are using same theme.

Answer (score 0):

If `app/design/frontend/yourtheme/something/layout/local.xml` contains:

```
<layout>
<cms_index_index>
<reference name="content">
    <block type="cms/block" name="home-page-block">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>home-page-block</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
</cms_index_index>
</layout>
```

In backend I have a static block with block identified `home-page-block`
Its contens is displayed in all store views.

Comment: this is not the issue of tag closing. I have asked something else. tags are closed. I want to call a static block on homepage of magento which have more then two stores based on language using same template for every store. Static block shows only at single store, on other stores, its not show up.

Comment: I edited the answer with details about how I tested this... works on my test env (Magento CE and Enterprise). If it's not displayed on your website than something else interferes with this.

Comment: Another thing that might cause the problem: the block should be visible in All Store Views (edit block Store View - All Store Views).